# PHP: How to get array in foreach to out foreach

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

I have query automatic, i using code igniter,
Structure table organization have field id and name.

```
 $get_organization = $this->db->query("SELECT id,name FROM organization")->result_array();
```

if i print_r variable $get_organization as below:

```
    Array (
         [0] => Array
          ( 
             [id] => 1
             [name] => orgone
          )

         [1] => Array
          (
             [id] => 2
             [name] => orgtwo
          )
   )
```

And for i get sum automatic i write code as below:

```
 foreach($get_organization as $bit){
     $id=$bit['id'];
     $name=preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/", "", $bit['name']);
     $getcabang[] = "SUM(CASE WHEN org_id = '$id' THEN total END) as $name";     
 }

 $cabang = implode(',',$getcabang);
```

And in table are looking to search the results is **laporan** with field **id, total, tanggal_laporan, org_id**.

```
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id, $cabang, tanggal_laporan FROM laporan GROUP BY tanggal_laporan")->result_array();
```

And then if i print_r variable $query i have result as below:

```
Array (
     [0] => Array
      ( 
         [orgone] => 218000
         [orgtwo] => 112000
         [tanggal_laporan] => 2012-11-04
      )

     [1] => Array
      (
         [orgone] => 198000
         [orgtwo] => 411000
         [tanggal_laporan] => 2012-11-05
      )

     [2] => Array
      (
         [orgone] => 513000
         [orgtwo] => 147000 
         [tanggal_laporan] => 2012-11-06
      )
 )
```

So my question, i want to result automatic as below:

```
$array_transform = array(
   [orgone] => "218000, 198000, 411000",
   [orgtwo] => "112000, 411000, 147000",
   [tanggal_laporan] => "2012-11-04, 2012-11-05, 2012-11-06",
);
```

And when it comes one more row of the table organization for example one row with name=orgthree, so result i want as:

```
$array_transform = array(
   [orgone] => "218000, 198000, 411000",
   [orgtwo] => "112000, 411000, 147000",
   [orgthree] => "0, 0, 0",
   [tanggal_laporan] => "2012-11-04, 2012-11-05, 2012-11-06",
);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer after the question was changed. This will process the fields into the structure you want withhout having to hard code the field names.

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/KL6Sdd9r)**

```
$array_transform = array();

foreach($array_from_mysql as $row)
{
    foreach($row as $field => $value)
    {
        if(isset($array_transform[$field]))
        {
            $array_transform[$field][] = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            $array_transform[$field] = array($value);
        }
    }
}

print_r($array_transform);
```

Comment: Hi MrCode thanks for reply, and sorry, but not like that, but I was asking the wrong question, now I've changed my question, will you please look at the question in the new. Thanks.

Comment: Hi MrCode, thanks for your code it work, but i cannot implode value there :-D

Comment: What/why are you trying to implode?

Comment: sorry I've made you bother, and I want to automatic data. result I just want my change, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array_from_mysql as $sub_array) {
    $result['total'][] = $sub_array['total'];
    $result['tanggal_laporan'][] = $sub_array['tanggal_laporan'];
}
```

Comment: Hi t1gor thanks for reply, and sorry, but not like that, but I was asking the wrong question, now I've changed my question, will you please look at the question in the new. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it's coming from a SQL query (as implied by the variable name) you could probably use a `GROUP BY` query with `GROUP_CONCAT` to get the data in the required format out of the DB without PHP needing to do anything clever.

I can't help much more than that with the actual query because you haven't shown us the original query, but read up more about it on the MySQL manual here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//group-by-functions.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi SDC thanks for reply, but i not success with group concat, i using Code Igniter, in code igniter, in code igniter cannot run query function group_concat, i get message Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::group_concat().

Comment: I don't know the Code Igniter DB classes, so I can't help with that, but I would be very surprised if there wasn't some way to do that kind of query using it -- a decent DB engine shouldn't prevent you from doing common SQL functions.

Comment: OK, so from that foreach or for how to get the data as my question above, because CI and PHP is the same for array problem. you try to look back code that I change it, and I also provide result data, so that my friends here can help me with the PHP code to manipulate arrays. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
    $array_transform = array();
    foreach ($array_from_mysql as $row) {
        foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
            if (!isset($array_transform[$name])) {
                $array_transform[$name] = array();
            }
            $array_transform[$name][] = $value;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi h20000000 thanks for reply, and sorry, but not like that, but I was asking the wrong question, now I've changed my question, will you please look at the question in the new. Thanks.

Comment: @AlanIchal I've changed the code to work with any amount of keys.

Comment: Hi h2ooooo, thanks for your code it work, but i cannot implode value there :-D

Comment: @AlanIchal Just use `implode(", ", $array_transform["orgone"]);` ?

Comment: sorry I've made you bother, and I want to automatic data. result I just want my change, Thanks.